# Why Are the Laws of Physics the Way They Are?

Tags: epistemology

Why does Newton's law of gravitiation look the way it does? Why is the Gravitiational Consntant this specific value? Why do Maxwell's Equations look the way they do? Why is it that abstract quantities we make up such as mass, charge, displacement, time etc... could be put into useful formula that accurately predict phenomena in the physical world?

I am aware that physical laws are merely abstractions, but the mathematical correspondance between many physical quantities we define is deduced almost purely emperically i.e. is not abstractly defined by us as human observers. Let me emphasise that this is not necessarily the case with all laws, for example Newton's Second Law "*F=ma*," where we define the force to be the product of mass and acceleration, there is nothing about the law that is "emperically deduced." It is purely a definition. However, the Second Law of Thermodynamics, Faraday's Law and Special Relativity are just a few examples of where we deduce "mathematically meaningful correspondance," purely due to emperical observation.

Why is that so? Why does our universe seem to exhibit mathematically significant correspondance? Please keep in mind that I am referring to emperically deduced laws of physics, not quantities we define.

Comment: Opinion-based questions are off-topic on this site.

Comment: The answer to this question is not necessarliy subjective. A formal approach to ontology i.e. mereology is not opinion-based.

Comment: We can easily imagine universes with very different laws of physics. No one knows why ours has the laws it has.

Comment: Please keep in mind that we make up many of these laws, however the astounding part is that emperical observation independent of our existence can be described by a mathematical model we made up !

Comment: *We define the force to be the product of mass and acceleration.* You should *not* think that force is defined as the product of mass times acceleration. If you think that way, $F=ma$ has no predictive value whatsoever!

Comment: But how do you measure force? We use newtonmeters based on stiffness, which we base on weights...from a dimensional analysis point of view...the unit of force is defined, and not measured. However, the linear "correlation" between mass and force could be thought of as an emperically observed "doubling of mass" corresponds to a "doubling in force" by definiton...not by observation? Please correct me.

Comment: You are supposed to think of $F$ as some known function of position and velocity (for example, as in the Lorentz force) so that $F=ma$ becomes the 2nd-order differential equation predicting the motion.

Comment: I’m getting a message to avoid extended discussions in comments, so I’ll stop. You can ask about measuring force as another question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105527/discussion-between-joeseph123-and-g-smith).

Comment: @Joeseph123, Not _that_ astounding. Math is the language that we invented specifically for describing how reality works--starting with how many sheep are in the corral, and working our way up to gravitation, quantum field theory, etc.

Comment: Let me put this into context: why can a formal language we made up describe something which we don't make up i.e. the physical world? Why can this be done?